# How to put css color style on particular row of ag ng2 grid in Angular2 on the value of column?

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to insert css styles on rows when column data value matches to my condition

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question needs to be fleshed out, include examples of what you have tried. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help with asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ElementRef** directive as below:

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {        
    this.sharedData = sharedResource.SharedComponent;        
} 

SetRowStyle(colValue)
{
    if (colValue == "yourCondition") {
         let tableCol= this.el.nativeElement.closest(".tableTd");
         tableCol.style.padding = 0;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have applied css on table column, furthermore you can find it's parent and apply css to row as well

Comment: A `[class]` binding property would be more concise and avoid the use of `ElementRef`.